# Cumulative Time Variable by Combining M/D/Y and NBA Game Clock data

Tags: r, time, data-manipulation

I am trying to create a cumulative time variable for an NBA shot log dataset which will combine three different measurements for the passage of time. I need to use 12-Game Clock in order to determine the time of a shot for a given NBA player since a quarter in the NBA is 12 minutes. Following the same logic, a shot in the second quarter with a game clock of 11:00 would correspond to a cumulative time of 12+(12-11)= 13 minutes. AM/PM does not exist in the game clock variable- it simply represents how many minutes and seconds have passed in the quarter.

| Date | Quarter | Game Clock (Min:Sec) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OCT 29, 2014 | 1 | 11:01 |
| OCT 29, 2014 | 3 | 2:42 |
| OCT 30, 2014 | 1 | 1:58 |
| NOV 01, 2014 | 2 | 1:15 |

Desired Output:

| Cumulative Time |
| --- |
| 00:00:59 |
| 00:45:58 |
| 24:10:02 |
| 72:34:45 |

Please let me know if you need more information. Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/nba-shot-logs

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you describe the Quarter effect on the output

Comment: A quarter is 12 minutes. Sorry I did not include the repeated measurements from one game. Will add more rows to the table so it makes sense.

Comment: it is okay.  I asked because I don't know the terminology in that game.  thanks for the reply

Comment: Should be better now.

Comment: Minutes Seconds

Comment: Please check the solution below. thanks

Comment: Can you explain the calculation? How is the first value `00:00:59`, and the second `00:45:58` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tedscr working with `times`-only can be confusing in R. The package `{lubridate}` comes with 3 different types, i.e. interval, duration, and periods. For the following I am using the `{hms}` packages that helps with formatting and parsing times and working with it as a period (:= hms independent of a [start]date).

Note: Under the hood, we work with seconds. Thus, you could also coerce all you have to numerical seconds or difftime and work with this.

To explain to you what is happening, I create a new column for each step.
You may want to combine this in a single operation to your liking.

```
library(hms)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

#----------------------- data -----------------------------
nba <- tibble::tribble(
     ~Date, ~Quarter, ~`Game.Clock.(Min:Sec)`,
   "OCT 29, 2014",       1L,                 "11:01",
   "OCT 29, 2014",       3L,                  "2:42",
   "OCT 30, 2014",       1L,                  "1:58",
   "NOV 01, 2014",       2L,                  "1:15"
   )

quarter <- hms::hms(minutes = 12)    # to create a "period" of 12 minutes

nba %>% 
  mutate(
#---- determine the time played in the current quarter
#---- as Game.Clock is a character emulating mm::ss add 00: to have hms!  
    GameClockPlayed = quarter - hms::parse_hms(paste0("00:", `Game.Clock.(Min:Sec)`) )
#---- simply add the previous quarters played to the current played time
#---- note: this returns "seconds"
   , CumGameClock = (Quarter * quarter) + GameClockPlayed
#---- use lubridate to nicely format the seconds played
   , CumGameClock2 = lubridate::seconds_to_period(CumGameClock))
)
```

This gives you:

```
  Date         Quarter `Game.Clock.(Min:Sec)` GameClockPlayed CumGameClock CumGameClock2
  <chr>          <int> <chr>                  <drtn>          <drtn>       <Period>     
1 OCT 29, 2014       1 11:01                   59 secs         779 secs    12M 59S      
2 OCT 29, 2014       3 2:42                   558 secs        2718 secs    45M 18S      
3 OCT 30, 2014       1 1:58                   602 secs        1322 secs    22M 2S       
4 NOV 01, 2014       2 1:15                   645 secs        2085 secs    34M 45S
```

If you need to do further math and the hms/lubirdate period construction is too cumbersome, you can apply `as.numeric()` to your `period` object. Likewise for the final presentation, you can coerce it back to the character formatting.